# Grant mysql access to remote servers without IP

Tags: mysql, scaling

I'm setting up a hosting scheme that will involve a master server and clone servers all accessing a remote mysql DB on its own server. As traffic increases/decreases I will be adding or removing clone servers.

As I understand it, you have to grant permissions to each new IP that will be accessing a DB when it is not being accessed locally. But I am wondering if it is possible to grant privileges in a secure way that I don't have to do it every time I add a clone server.

If it has any relevance, I'm doing this on Rackspace, using cloud servers.

Comment: I haven't worked with scaling, but every instance will have the IP address in the `/etc/hosts` file. Maybe you could write a script as part of the image which will read the file and communicate its IP address to the DB server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using Rackspace, and I am accessing the database on a server in the same region, I can use the service IP - therefore I can grant access to a user with the `%` wildcard character to match every host on a subnet like this:

```
'user'@'10.%'
```

[MySQL account name documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/account-names.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a range of IP addresses, you can just add a single entry for the range as well as other options.  It should be pretty easy for you to figure out by looking at the MySQL docs, specifically the first table listed [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connection-access.html).

Comment: What about using a hostname, ie. `user@example.com` instead of `user@192.168.0.1`?

Comment: What about it? Hostname examples are listed along with IP addresses at the link.  What aren't you understanding?

Comment: Do you favor one solution over the other? I'm guessing that with hostname, DNS resolving to an IP might slow down the connection, but it seems like a much easier solution to implement. By the way, what link are you talking about.

Comment: Then I think you will be using the public facing ethernet port. I think it would be better to use the private port?

Comment: @Paul yea, I am using the private IP (Rackspace service IP). Does that preclude using a hostname then?

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow only SSL-connections to the servers from any IP-address that have valid SSL key.
Refer to the MySQL manual chapter 6.3.6 for details.
Keep in mind that SSL produce some overhead and can decrease overall performance.